# Getting current path when handling rejections

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'd like to know how it would be possible to get HTTP path in Warp's rejection handler? I've got the following rejection method:

```rust
pub(crate) async fn handle(err: Rejection) -> Result<impl Reply, Infallible> {
    let response = if err.is_not_found() {
        HttpApiProblem::with_title_and_type_from_status(StatusCode::NOT_FOUND)
    } else if let Some(e) = err.find::<warp::filters::body::BodyDeserializeError>() {
        HttpApiProblem::with_title_and_type_from_status(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST)
            .set_detail(format!("{}", e))
    } else if let Some(e) = err.find::<Error>() {
        handle_request_error(e)
    } else if let Some(e) = err.find::<warp::reject::MethodNotAllowed>() {
        HttpApiProblem::with_title_and_type_from_status(StatusCode::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
            .set_detail(format!("{}", e))
    } else {
        error!("handle_rejection catch all: {:?}", err);

        HttpApiProblem::with_title_and_type_from_status(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    };

    Ok(response.to_hyper_response())
}
```

For instance, I'd call `curl localhost:1234/this-aint-valid-path/123` and would like to have access to `/this-aint-valid-path/123` for logging purposes as well as returning this as part of the error response.

Answer (score 0):

It loos like the method `err.is_not_found()` checks whether the reason matches `Reason::NotFound`, which is an enumeration variant with no parameters. `Rejection` structs have no additional metadata beyond their reason, so the code in your question cannot be modified to solve your problem. It is however possible to create a custom reason with whatever metadata you want. The method you're looking for to create that `Rejection` object is called `custom`, and the docs for it can be found [here](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.5/warp/reject/fn.custom.html).

Comment: Hello, I perfectly understand that, however, it's not only about `Reason::NotFound`, but rather all possible rejections.

Comment: I think you need to make a custom rejection object with whatever metadata you're going to use, it doesn't look like warp has anything built-in to make it easier. If it's a small project and you're not concerned about design, you might be able to get away with storing data in a `static mut` or something to hack your way around those constraints (don't tell the rust gods I said that). There really doesn't look like there's a good solution to this :/

Comment: What else I was trying to look at was using https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.5/warp/filters/path/fn.full.html but couldn't wrap my head around how to use it properly within the rejection :|